# Angular Check-All box is selecting disabled checkbox in ngx data table

Tags: angular, checkboxlist

In ngx-data table I have disabled the checkbox of some rows based on some codition. If I click select all checkbox it is selecting the disabled checkbox also. 
How to resolve it, it should not select the disabled checkbox.

Please provide me the solution.
Here I have added the code.

**HTML**

```
<ngx-datatable-column [width]="30" [sortable]="false" [canAutoResize]="false" [draggable]="false" [resizeable]="false">
          <ng-template ngx-datatable-header-template let-value="value" let-allRowsSelected="allRowsSelected"
            let-selectFn="selectFn">
            <input type="checkbox" [checked]="allRowsSelected" (change)="selectFn(!allRowsSelected)" />
          </ng-template>
          <ng-template ngx-datatable-cell-template let-row="row" let-value="value" let-isSelected="isSelected" let-onCheckboxChangeFn="onCheckboxChangeFn">
            <input type="checkbox" [checked]="isSelected" (change)="onCheckboxChangeFn($event)" [disabled]="defaultRecord(row)"/>
          </ng-template>
        </ngx-datatable-column>
```

**TS File**

```
 defaultRecord(row) {
    if (row.username === "excadmin") {
      this.buttonDisabled = true;
      return true;
    } else {
      this.buttonDisabled = false;
      return false;
    }
  }
```

Comment: can you provide your html?

Comment: Instead of disabling it with ngx-data-column use [checkboxable]="false" ?

Comment: I checked with [checkboxable] = "false" but getting following error:
an't bind to 'checkboxable' since it isn't a known property of 'ngx-datatable'.

Comment: yes because that property is of ngx-data-column of ngx-datatable

Answer (score 0):

You can add `(select)="onSelect($event)` to your ngx-datatable header and then define the following function in your typescript:

```
selected = []

onSelect({ selected }) {
  this.selected.splice(0, this.selected.length);
  this.selected = selected.filter(e => this.defaultRecord(e));
}
```

In this way you will avoid selecting disabled checkbox rows